# What is the proper way to refer to an island?

Tags: nombres-propios

Some friends of mine live on Rota (an island off Guam). I might tease them that "La Isla Rota" means "Broken Island."

Pero, fuera de broma, what would be the proper (no pun intended) way to refer to their domicile in Spanish: La Isla *de* Rota? I assume so, because "Treasure Island" is "La Isla del Tesoro"...

Comment: I guess that the official name in Spanish is just "Rota" but since I have heard "vive en el Peñón (de Gibraltar)" maybe "**La** isla de Rota" is accepted. I know for sure that we don't use an article to refer to each individual island in Spain (Mallorca, Ibiza, etc.), just as a group (Las Islas Baleares, las Islas Canarias). We also refer to "La Isla de Pascua" but it seems that that is actually its official name (Isla de Pascua) and with Rota I don't know if it's Rota or Isla de Rota.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rota`, `la isla de Rota`, `isla de Rota` are ok, even `isla Rota`. If the place is renown you could omit `isla` (e.g. Madagascar, Mallorca, Gran Canaria, Galápagos). Sometimes it sounds nicer to compound the name adding `isla` (or `islas`) but again, unless the name of the place includes the word `isla` (e.g. Isla de Margarita, Isla de Pascua) then you can omit it.